# Sentence structure for "all I need for now is you"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

My younger brother just asked me to explain this and I am not that sure. Is this an inversion or what? I have thought about the song "All I want for Christmas is you", they share the same structure so I guess this should be alright too. Can anyone explain it clearly?

Comment: For this to be an inversion, we would need to invert something. But all the words are in the normal order. X is Y. Jane is brave. Music is fun. All I need is you.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Isn't *All I need is you* an "inversion" of the normal subject+verb sequence *You are all I need* (where "you" sounds much more like a natural verb subject than "all I need")? But I must also say that whereas *Brave is Jane* sounds like a credible "literary inversion", *Fun is music* sounds like an extreme example of Yoda-speak.